# C++ accessing object method through array of pointers to objects

Tags: c++

I have trouble figuring out how to access bject method through array of pointers to objects.

I have an **env** object of Environment class:

```
Environment env;
```

My Environment has some object pointers as well as a dynamic array of pointers:

```
    static Robot *robot;
    static Obstacle *obstacle;
    static Object **objects;
```

So inside **objects** I can have robots and obstacles:

But now when I want to access a method of an object in the **objects** array, how can I do that? I tried

```
    Environment env;
    Robot *robot;

    robot = env.objects[0];
    robot->setSpeed(175);
```

But it didn't work. I got an error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘Object*’ to ‘Robot*’
```

What am I doing wrong?

**PS: Robot inherits from Object.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does `Robot` inherit from `Object`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Robot` inherits from `Object` you have to use either [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) or [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to cast the pointer:

```
robot = static_cast<Robot*>(Environment::objects[0]);
```

As a side note, I also recommend you to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of the array, and a smart pointer like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of the raw pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the Object* to a Robot*. Assuming Robot inherits from Object. I advise you to use dynamic_cast:

```
Robot* robot = dynamic_cast<Robot*>(env.objects[0]);
if (robot != NULL) {
    robot->setSpeed(14);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cast your object from Object* to Robot*. However, you have to make sure it is a Robot object otherwise your application will crash.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
class Object
{
};

class Robot : public Object
{
  public:
  int speed;
  void setSpeed(int newSpeed){ speed = newSpeed; }
};

int main()
{
  Object* obj = new Robot();
  ((Robot*)obj)->setSpeed(4);
  std::cout << "Speed is: " << ((Robot*)obj)->speed << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't implicitly assign pointer of base class to pointer of derived class. If you need to do this, use `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

*objects* is declared with type Object**, which means that objects[0] is of type Object*. You cannot assign an Object* to a Robot*. Assuming Robot is a class derived from Object and has at least one virtual member function, you can do

```
robot = dynamic_cast<Robot*>(object[0]);
```

This will perform the cast, or set *robot* to the null pointer value if object[0] happens to not be a Robot. If you know for certain that it is a Robot, you can use static_cast() instead.

Answer (score 0):

your object does not seem to be a Robot* or a pointer to a subclass of it.